# How to select every 4th div inside another div CSS Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I possibly select every 4th div (4 - 8 - 12 - 16 and so on..) if I have a structure like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div></div> <!-- I want this div -->
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought about using `nth-of-type` but I can't get any result with it.. Can someone help me?

Comment: Not sure how the marked `div` is the 4th `div`. Are you looking for the `div` inside the 4th first level `div`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
div:nth-of-type(4n) > div > div:first-child {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Fiddle 1**: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6Laay9s6/

This will work even if your entire structure is nested in a wrapper(s), and/or there are elements before this structure.

**Fiddle 2** (*nested wrapper*): http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6Laay9s6/2/

And this:

**Fiddle 3** (*with elements*): http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6Laay9s6/3/

Answer (score 3):

I'm using body as main selector since I don't know if you use a wrapper

```
body div:nth-child(4n) div div:first-child {
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6atkjur/1/)**

If the structure you provided is inside a different named wrapper, use that wrapper in stead of `body`.

Comment: And what if the OP has some element before the first `div`? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6atkjur/3/)

Comment: @vucko Then he has to wrap his selectable elements.

Comment: To clarify timo's point, add a wrapper div around your series of divs.  http://jsfiddle.net/j6atkjur/7/

Comment: And if someone adds to that div some content, still won't work. That why we have `:first-of-type` and `:nth-of-type` selectors, like @Abhitalks posted, which is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for [nth-child Selector Css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```
div:nth-child(4) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I made an edit and it got rejected, I'll add it as a post.

### Timo Posted

I'm using body as main selector since I don't know if you use a wrapper

```
body div:nth-child(4n) div div:first-child {
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6atkjur/1/)**

If the structure you provided is inside a different named wrapper, use that wrapper in stead of `body`.

### I Added this to it, to address an issue

**Edit**

ISSUE : If an element is added before the div's, it will throw out the context, like **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6atkjur/3/)**

SOLUTION : To counter this, you need to add a class around the content, like **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6atkjur/6/)**